# How to make an app available for other users after installation?

Tags: windows, installation, windows-xp, windows-installer, regedit

I hope there is a way to do this, Let me explain it:
When you install a software on Windows, you are asked to do it for everyone or just for the current user. Well, I made a  mistake, I installed it just for me but now I realize it must be for everyone...
Is there a way to do it without reinstalling?
Being honest, I don't remember if I clicked "Everyone" or "just me", but I'm getting "Runtime Error" when trying to execute it with another user, that's why I guess I installed it wrong.
i think there must be a place in there regedit where it is configured, in that case there should be no problem with editing it to make the app available for other users.

Thanks

Comment: This is not a programming or programmers tools related question, and is off topic here. The [faq] and [about] pages have specific details about the types of questions that should be asked here. Voting to close as off topic. You may want to delete it and ask instead at [su], where it is more appropriate. Good luck.

Comment: May I suggest you visit also https://superuser.com/questions/1435459/share-application-program-for-all-users-on-windows-10/1467995#1467995, because the answers there may apply to you.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Installer doesn't support changing the installation context even during an upgrade. The only way to change from per-user to per-machine is to uninstall and reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the program.  If the program has registry entries or program data (C:\Documents & Settings{user}) specific to your user, it's likely best to uninstall and reinstall with the other option.

Most basic programs, however, only tweak what start menu the program shows up in.  If that's the case, and you can find the Start Menu group (right click Start -> Explore) under the specific user, you should be able to copy that group to other users and move right along.