# Share Application Program for All Users on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, user-accounts, user-profiles, user

Just setup a Windows 10 Laptop, I have one base account which is administrator and 2 user accounts to be used by two other users.

I installed an application ( [Scratch Desktop](https://scratch.mit.edu/download) ) from base user account but other users are unable to see this.

Installation steps did not prompt in any way to make it available to all users.
How to I make this program available to all users, anything that involves not copying the full program to each user profile folders is appreciated.

OS: Windows 10 Pro

Comment: The application developers would have to offer this option in the installer. If the application is designed to only run in the User context, you would not be able to modify it effectively to run for all users.

Comment: “Installation steps did not prompt in any way to make it available to all users.“ - Only an Administrator can install an application for all users.  “How to I make this program available to all users, anything that involves not copying the full program to each user profile folders is appreciated.” - Are you the shortcut wasn’t created instead of the actual application being installed to the profile?  Are you sure other users cannot run the application by manually starting the executable in the installation directory?  Edit and clarify your question

Comment: Installed using administrator account.  The full application was installed in C:\Users\XYZAdminUser\AppData\Local\Programs\scratch-desktop\

Comment: I think that the fact that the app was installed in your XYZAdminUser's private AppData folders is what causes the issue; see my proposed solution below which worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

**What Worked For Me**

I literally moved the application folder from my administrator account folders at C:\Users[MYUSERNAME]\AppData\Roaming[MYPROGRAMNAME] to C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming[MYPROGRAMNAME].

I did have to manually create the directory path C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming\ myself because it didn't exist.

Once I moved the program folder in there though, the program still ran on my administrator account just fine (which it always did), but what's even better: it now also ran just fine for my standard accounts without any additional effort!

I suppose I should state that I did also go back and login as my standard accounts and redirected the "Starts In" and "Target" fields for the program icon properties on their desktops so that they pointed instead to the C:\Users\Public\AppData\Roaming[MYPROGRAMNAME] folder. The software ran even before that, but I only took this step so that the program icon would match the image expected. But that was trivial. Everything was running fine at this point anyway, and ran fine afterwards too.